# JSON output works in postman but not in python post request

Tags: python, json, http, postman, httprequest

I have a python code thats supposed to create a json file that i use as the data in my post requests.

The variable looks like this:

```
request="""{"QueryString":"{\\"search_type\\":5,\\"project_id_list\\":[\\"1\\"],\\"user_key\\":\\"a\\",\\"options\\":{\\"pagination\\":{\\"page_num\\":1,\\"page_size\\":200},\\"projection\\":{\\"name\\":1},\\"condition_group\\":{\\"conjunction\\":\\"AND\\",\\"conditions\\":[],\\"groups\\":[]},\\"facet\\":{\\"fields\\":[],\\"type\\":0,\\"update_one\\":false},\\"groups\\":[],\\"sort\\":[]},\\"search_types\\":[]}","SearchType":4}"""
```

When I print the above variable I get the following output:

```
{"QueryString":"{\"search_type\":5,\"project_id_list\":[\"1\"],\"user_key\":\"a\",\"options\":{\"pagination\":{\"page_num\":1,\"page_size\":200},\"projection\":{\"name\":1},\"condition_group\":{\"conjunction\":\"AND\",\"conditions\":[],\"groups\":[]},\"facet\":{\"fields\":[],\"type\":0,\"update_one\":false},\"groups\":[],\"sort\":[]},\"search_types\":[]}","SearchType":4}
```

When I use the following output on my postman request it works as I expect it to. But when I use the same variable to send the http request with the following function I get an error.

```
url = 'www.myurl.com'
body =request
headers = {
'Token': 'sas'}
r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
print(r.text) #prints an error {"statusCode":-1,"errMsg":"unexpected end of JSON input"}
```

Why is my output working on postman but not in python itself?

Comment: Please add the postman screenshot of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code is working in postman , You can generate python code from postman itself:

[image]

[image]